# how to solve equations

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I am trying to find the values of L and \theta, but mathematica is unable to produce output. My code is given below, where the value of k is fixed, i.e., 0.75, but the value of B can be positive or negative.

```
Solve[{
   1/r^4 2 (r^2 + (L - B r^k + 
          B r^k Cos[\[Theta]])^2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 - (-2 + r) (L - 
          B r^k + B r^k Cos[\[Theta]]) (L + B (-1 + k) r^k - 
          B (-1 + k) r^k Cos[\[Theta]]) Csc[\[Theta]]^2) == 0,
   -(1/(r^3))
     2 (-2 + r) (L - B r^k + 
        B r^k Cos[\[Theta]]) (B r^
         k + (L - B r^k) Cos[\[Theta]]) Csc[\[Theta]]^3 == 0},
  {L, \[Theta]}]
```

Can anyone please help me to solve these equations.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to introduce variables $x$ and $y$ in place of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$, like this

```
eq1 = 1/r^4 2 (r^2 + (L - B r^k + 
          B r^k Cos[θ])^2 Csc[θ]^2 - (-2 + r) (L - 
         B r^k + B r^k Cos[θ]) (L + B (-1 + k) r^k - 
         B (-1 + k) r^k Cos[θ]) Csc[θ]^2) == 0;

eq2 = -(1/(r^3)) 2 (-2 + r) (L - B r^k + 
      B r^k Cos[θ]) (B r^
        k + (L - B r^k) Cos[θ]) Csc[θ]^3 == 0;

eq3 = x^2 + y^2 == 1;

eqns = {eq1, eq2, eq3} /. Cos[θ] -> x /. Csc[θ] -> (1/y);

s = Solve[eqns, {L, x, y}] // Simplify;
```

Then use `ArcTan[x,y]` to recover solutions for $\theta$.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use the Weierstrass substitution `θ -> 2 ArcTan[u]`.